# ANOVA for three subsets on R

Tags: r, subset, anova

I am a real novice with R. I have a .csv data file. 
I have created 3 subsets of data, which represent three different groups responses to a questionnaire.

```
p_groupFMI = subset(data, M_freq==1) #n= 
c_groupFMI = subset(data, M_freq==2) #n=
i_groupFMI = subset(data, M_freq==3) #n=
```

I want to try and compare the means of these three groups with an ANOVA. Then do a turkey test. Can I do this without having to try and create levels and the like?

I have tried

```
aov.data = aov(data$Mean ~ data$M_freq, data=data)
summary(aov.data)
TukeyHSD(aov.data)
```

but this does not seem to work well.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just a quick note- it is much easier for everyone to help answer a question if it is contains "toy data" that we can run on our end. I've included this in my answer. Good luck!

Comment: An easy way to include your data would be to include in your question the result of running `dput(data)` in your R console.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some data, three groups are denoted as such with a grouping variable, of type factor.

```
n1 <- n2 <- n3 <- 4    
df.test <- as.data.frame(list(
    grouping = as.factor(c(rep(1,times=n1),rep(2,times=n2),rep(3,times=n3))), #arbitrary factor
    data = c(rnorm(n=n1,mean=1),rnorm(n=n2,mean=10),rnorm(n=n3,mean=11)))) #random data
head(df.test)
#   grouping       data
# 1        1  2.1026786
# 2        1  0.4464325
# 3        1 -1.0131310
# 4        1  1.6502438
# 5        2 10.8733848
# 6        2  9.3680943
```

To test if the group means for groups 1, 2, and 3 differ significantly:

```
anova <- aov(df.test$data ~ df.test$grouping)
summary(anova)
#                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
# df.test$grouping  2 280.93  140.47   111.4
# Residuals         9  11.34    1.26        
#                    Pr(>F)    
# df.test$grouping 4.47e-07 ***
# Residuals                    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  
# 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And you can run a Tukey test:

```
TukeyHSD(anova)
#   Tukey multiple comparisons of means
#     95% family-wise confidence level
# 
# Fit: aov(formula = df.test$data ~ df.test$grouping)
# 
# $`df.test$grouping`
#           diff       lwr       upr     p adj
# 2-1  9.9632077  7.746675 12.179740 0.0000014
# 3-1 10.5404363  8.323904 12.756969 0.0000009
# 3-2  0.5772286 -1.639304  2.793761 0.7542212
```