# I want to run an ANOVA in R on species diversity between 3 depths but there are 5 locations in each depth

Tags: r

I have data of species diversity in a table which has species diversity as one column , depth as one column and location as another. My question is how diversity changes with depth.
I have 3 depths eg D1,D2 and D3 . In each depth we had 5 separate locations . I would like to run an ANOVA on species diversity but just against depth but not sure how to run it

I have tried the anova function but not sure if I've used the data correctly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ANOVA - comparing 3 groups in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173207/anova-comparing-3-groups-in-r)

Comment: There are plenty of other old questions that could help. Just search "R anova". Here's another one: [ANOVA for three subsets on R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55623886/anova-for-three-subsets-on-r)

Comment: Could you add some details and some code to make this a [mcve]? As it stands, your question is pretty much impossible to answer, and per your other comments it seems like it's more about plotting than running an anova?

Answer (score 0):

You should first be clear about the design, i.e., is it between, within or mixed? Plus, `anova` is used for model comparisons and not the right function for you. Use `aov()` or `ezANOVA()` instead.

If each row (observation) is a unique specie, then it is between subjects. You can use the code as simple as below:

```
aov(diversity ~ depth, data)
```

However, if each specie has multiple rows (observation), it is within subjects then. You need to specify depth as the within factor like below:

```
aov(diversity ~ depth + Error(ID/depth), data)
```

Comment: Hi. Yeh so I'm looking at diversity between depths so initial data was a list of species , their abundance per location and there are 5 locations within each depth . But wanted to plot just between depths

Comment: @AmyBethan This sounds like a different question related to ggplot.